# Returning value for given key in js and d3 - do i have to loop?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, associative-array, key-value

Sorry for asking this. It seems so simple. I have data in this structure:

```
[
{key: "fred", value: {Object} },
{key: "sally", value: {Object} },
{key: "terry", value: {Object} }
]
```

How do I return value where key="sally"? Surely there's some way other than looping (it's a long array)?
Thanks

Comment: `ARRAY.filter(function(item){ return item.key==='sally'; })`

Comment: [`arr.find(o => o.key = 'sally')`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/hbz0Lk6q/)

Answer (score 2):

There is no other way than looping. It may be hidden but all methods will eventually come down to looping. If you are going to perform the search operation multiple times you can index your data. It will use more memory but loop only once.

In pure JS (ES5):

```
var indexed = arr.reduce(function(r, e) {
    r[e.key] = e.value;
    return r;
}, {});

console.log(indexed["sally"]);
console.log(indexed["fred"]);
```

With D3:

```
var indexed = d3.map(arr, function(d) { return d.key});

console.log(indexed.get("sally").value);
console.log(indexed.get("fred").value);
```